# TypeError: a.union is not a function

Tags: javascript, union, jsts

I'm trying to get the union of two polygons but every time I try I get a `TypeError: a.union is not a function` error.

Here's my code:

```
import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js';
import GeoJSONWriter from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONWriter.js';

let reader = new GeoJSONReader();
let writer = new GeoJSONWriter();

var a = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[
    [-97.82742,30.44107],
    [-97.82753,30.44087],
    [-97.82426,30.43791],
    [-97.82259,30.43820],
    [-97.82233,30.43816],
    [-97.82046,30.44090],
    [-97.82106,30.44153],
    [-97.82208,30.44232],
    [-97.82221,30.44238],
    [-97.82450,30.44352],
    [-97.82461,30.44357],
    [-97.82552,30.44387],
    [-97.82727,30.44114],
    [-97.82742,30.44107]
]]};

var b = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[
    [-97.81808,30.43962],
    [-97.81585,30.43878],
    [-97.81445,30.43504],
    [-97.81522,30.42965],
    [-97.81685,30.42817],
    [-97.81847,30.42851],
    [-97.82310,30.43025],
    [-97.83076,30.42995],
    [-97.83162,30.43439],
    [-97.82789,30.43968],
    [-97.81808,30.43962]
]]};

a = reader.read(a);
b = reader.read(b);

var result = a.union(b);

result = writer.write(result);

console.log(result);
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "jsts": "^2.9.3"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the shortcut methods (.union, .buffer ...) are not available when importing the ES6 modules. It is mentioned at the bottom of the readme file: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/tree/master.

The union operation can be imported and used with:

```
import UnionOp from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/union/UnionOp.js';
// ... 
var result = UnionOp.union(a, b)
```