# how to do difference operation with jsts / ES6 module

Tags: differences, jsts

In [TypeError: a.union is not a function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/461639/17847) I asked about how to do a union operation and was told that to do so I'd need to do this:

```
import UnionOp from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/union/UnionOp.js';
// ... 
var result = UnionOp.union(a, b)
```

So how do I do a difference operation? http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/ mentions them, however, when I look .\node_modules\jsts\org\locationtech\jts\operation I'm not seeing anything like "difference". Maybe it's none-the-less there and I'm just not finding it? Maybe you just can't do the difference operatin with the ES6 module of jsts?

Comment: `difference` function is in `jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/overlay/OverlayOp.js`